# Правильно ли я передаю массив перегруженной функции?

Tags: c++

Мне нужно в главной функции заполнить и создать массив типа double, потом вызвать перегруженную функцию, передав ей массив действительных чисел.

Правильно ли я выполнил задание? У меня есть сомнения по этому поводу...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Arrayy(double * Array, int kol);
void Arrayy(double * Array, int kol) {
    cout << "float: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
        cout << Array[i] << "\t";
    }
}

void Arrayy(float * Array, int kol);
void Arrayy(float * Array, int kol) {
    cout << "float: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
        cout << Array[i] << "\t";
    }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "");
    double Array[10];
    int kol;
    cout << " Введите количество элементов < 10  : \n\n";
    cin >> kol;
    for(int i = 0; i < kol; i++) {
        cout << " Введите " << i + 1 << " елемент > ";
        cin >> Array[i];
    }
    Arrayy(Array, kol);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Да, есть такое. Исправлено. Спасибо

Comment: А как можно передать иначе? Функция вызовется та которая соответствует типам аргументов.

Comment: А зачем вы перед определением функций их отдельно объявляете? `void Arrayy(double * Array, int kol);` и др. - лишние.